# pm2 list clusters and used/available CPUs

Tags: node.js, pm2

I just started using pm2 and wanted to already use the cluster mode as I'll be managing multiple nodejs applications on my VPS.

The documentation is vague and the monit/monitor functions don't show the used CPUs.
My VPS is running an Intel Xeon E5-2620 v3 @ 2.4ghz x 4 cores.

For testing purposes I started my Node service using 1 CPU.
It shows just 1 process.

When I stop it and rerun `pm2 start index.js -i 0` it still shows 1 process.

When I delete all the processes and run `pm2 start index.js -i 0` it now shows 4 processes.

If you want to refactor the available core count for each application, is it only possible through deletion of the processes?
Is the only way to differentiate the applications by process name? As it just duplicates them all and uses the `index` as name.

Sorry if this is confusing. Edits openly accepted.

Answer (score 0):

That seems about right since `pm2 start -i 0 index.js` is the same as `pm2 start -i max index.js` which will spread the cluster across all cpus.

The process ID's are a great way to distinguish them.  You could also use a name (-n) to add identity to the application.  With the following commands you should be able to start up, delete, and reload cluster processes as needed.  You could even use --watch in development so you don't need to restart the cluster manually.

```
pm2 start -n webserver -i 4 index.js --watch
```

To add a process or 3 (-f required):

```
pm2 start -n webserver -f -i 1 index.js

pm2 start -n webserver -f -i 3 index.js
```

To cat running processes:

```
pm2 ls
```

To remove one use ID number:

```
pm2 del 2
```

To reload one or all:

```
pm2 reload 1

pm2 reload all
```

To programmatically access the instance number in a cluster use `NODE_APP_INSTANCE`:

```js
const app = require('express')()
const PORT = 6767

app.all('/*', (req, res) => {
  const { NODE_APP_INSTANCE } = process.env
  res.send(`Sent from instance ${NODE_APP_INSTANCE}`)
})

app.listen(PORT, console.log('LISTENING TO PORT', PORT))
```

If you're running something complex you should consider using ecosystem files.  Check sources below.

Sources:

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/load-balancing/#cluster-environment-variable

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/